# Wrong password issue in Samsung Galaxy SII

Tags: android, sip, voip, asterisk

I am developing one SIP based application to make and receive a call.I have used shared preference to store the all the registration related data like user-name,password,context etc.This data are also stored in [A2billing](http://www.asterisk2billing.org/).And i have used [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) [Realtime](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime) to register sip user in application.

The main issue is that when i am running my application it works fine in all the other devices except Samsung Galaxy S2. On this device SIP user is not get registered and on **asterisk console it gives me a error of Wrong password.**

I cant configure what the actually issue is because its **runs perfectly on other devices except galaxy SII(4.0.3).currently i have tried with HTC phones and galaxy SII(2.3.6) and it worked fine**

If you have any idea and suggestion regarding this please share with me so i can workaround with this.

Thanks in Advance

**Solved:**

Finally the problem is solved when i uninstalled the Avast Antivirus from the device. i think Avast was causing a problem while accessing the data from sharedPrefrences don't know why. yeah but now i need to searched about that about, how do we avoid this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the native Android SIP stack or your own, linked in your app? If you are using the native one, might be a bug in the firmware. Debug your app and check if it is reading/writing the proper password. Then capture traffic with Wireshark, etc. and check what exactly is being sent over the wire(less). Then compare with traffic from other devices that work. Rinse and repeat until you pinpoint whose fault the error is.

Comment: i am using own sip stack library which is MjSip. And can you give me some details about Wireshark?

Comment: Here it is: http://www.wireshark.org/. It might be easier to check Asterisk debug logs first to spot any obvious differences.